# Laravel 5.2: ModelNotFoundException for specific models

Tags: php, laravel

I'm fairly new to coding in Laravel, and I've been following the Laravel Basics videos by Jeffery Way. Right now I'm working on building my own site that will allow users to register, send and receive messages, and post to a forum.

I'm setting up sending/receiving messages and have it working well enough, but what I want to do is safe-guard against a user trying to send a message to an invalid username.

The form is very basic for now: 'send_to' takes a username, 'title', and 'body'.

My Message model has a mutator that queries the database for that username and sets the 'send_to' field to that user's id.

```
    public function setSendToAttribute($value)
    {
        $user = User::where('name', $value)->firstOrFail();

        $this->attributes['send_to'] = $user->id;
    }
```

What I'd like to do is catch an exception if the username is invalid. I've done that with the Handler.php file as below:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException)
        return $e->getmessage();
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

So this works great and will will return the message "No query results for model [App\User]. What I'd prefer to do though is set it so it returns to the form again with the title and body filled out, and an error message saying that the username is not registered.

One other part to this, can this be done separately from all ModelNotFoundExceptions so if I'm trying to look up a specific message it won't return that a User was not found?

Comment: I would recommend that you do the user checking inside your controller. You want to validate the information and then send the appropriate message to the user or carry on with the task. I would also recommend to use mutators only for formatting values, this is not a rule, but mutators are for changing the data before persisting it to the database. The way you have, you're "hiding" your logic inside a mutator, which is counter-intuitive. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hiding the logic inside a mutator, you can create a FormRequest or validate the user in your controller.

Using validation rules, you can check the input for user existence, and redirect back on failure, or return a 422 error in case that you're using an ajax request (with the header Accept: application/json)

I'd highly recommend you to read about validation and check this specific rule I link below:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-exists

Then, once you're sure that the user exists in the database (remember to validate that the user is unique when you create it), you can write some logic to insert the user id instead of the username, if you want of course.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you! I used the validation to check the user exists, and left the mutator. Works like a charm!